# I can't run PyCharm Community on Windows7 after install anaconda 2

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run PyCharm Community on Windows as usual after install anaconda2.

I added to my path and the interpreter of PyCharm Community, but there are many errors appear when I open PyCharm Community to work on my project. Why?

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actual error is located _at the bottom_ of the traceback. You've missed it.

Comment: Text is always vastly preferable to screenshots. Please copy everything from the Python Console into question.

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading version 3 of bycharm....thank you for your comments